# Android - SimpleDateFormat IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'u'

Tags: java, android

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'u'
```

Here is my Code:

```
long ticket = 1473808310826L;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("u");
String test = sdf.format(ticket);
```

Using: **JDK 8**

`u` is used in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of `SimpleDateFormat`:

> Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)

Comment: What version of Android are you using? The `u` format was added in Java 7, so if your Android is running Java 6, it won't work.

Comment: Andreas,  android 6.01

Comment: Andreas, what version of Android do i need to be running on my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of `SimpleDateFormat` is misleading (as of *09/16/2016*, for future readers).

There is no `u` pattern character in Android.

From the source code of `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
static final String PATTERN_CHARS = "GyMdkHmsSEDFwWahKzZLc";

// ...

private void validatePatternCharacter(char format) {
    int index = PATTERN_CHARS.indexOf(format);
    if (index == -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown pattern character '"
            + format + "'");
    }
}
```

To get the current day of the week, you could do something like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

// if you do not wish to use the current time, but a specific one
// calendar.setTimeInMillis(yourTimeInMillis);

switch (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) {
    case Calendar.MONDAY:
        // monday
        break;
    case Calendar.TUESDAY:
        // tuesday
        break;
    // ...
}
```